# How to format text to looks like code in wordpress like stackoverflow {} tool?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need to format text in posts using WordPress to look like a code. Like here in stackoverflow we use { } to separate the code from the text. I need to do the same when I write my blogs in Wordpress

```
Example ....
code will look like that !
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you like the one used here: http://inturnets.com/2012/06/a-nice-tackling-with-jquery-and-css.html ?

It's the syntaxhighlighter wp plugin, http://www.viper007bond.com/wordpress-plugins/syntaxhighlighter/ , a very customisable one and finally you are using simple tags like **[html] html code [/html]** or **[css] css code [/css]**

Good luck! :)

Comment: yes i need that. The same format you use for code in that link http://inturnets.com/2012/06/a-nice-tackling-with-jquery-and-css.html

Comment: you mean you use syntaxhighlighter plugin ?

Comment: that is right, I remember before to use it I've searched a lot and that was the best which fits my needs, I needed it to be very customisable and easy to use.

Comment: Welcome! Don't forget to read first the plugin instructions, will help you to get the most possible from that plugin for your needs. :)

Comment: Is there a list of supported languages somewhere? I don't see one and it doesn't seem to work with at least 1 of mine.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress has a preformatted paragraph style that works OK without any plugins.  Just select the text and then select the Preformatted style on the left side of the formatting bar:

[image: Illustration showing Preformatted paragraph style in WordPress]

I had installed a plugin, but then found this simpler and it works fine for my purposes.

Comment: you are right! very simple and not plugin required! Also, this is the only feasible solution for me since I am using wordpress.com which prevents you from installing third-party plugins.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful to you

http://textformat.in/

Please do vote if it worth